# Redirecting REQUEST_URI through virtual subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been working on a website for some time now, and I got stuck when it came to url redirection. I successfully created virtual subdomains for pretty profile pages, but I have a problem with the remaining parameters.

What I am trying to do is, when someone types "username.mysite.net/about" to the address line, he/she should be redirected to "profile.php?u=username&t=about". Currently, people who try to reach "username.mysite.net" get successfully redirected to "profile.php?u=username". But when I try to pass the REQUEST_URI too like "username.mysite.net/about", it gives a 404 error.

Below I copy the relevant parts of my htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.net
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).mysite.net
RewriteRule ^$ /profile.php?u=%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

I would really appreciate some help. Thank you already...

Answer (score 0):

A slight tweak should make this work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.net
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).mysite.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?u=%1&t=$1 [L]
```